# Mysql: where in returns no rows when used with json_extract

Tags: mysql, where-in, json-extract

I am somewhat puzzled with the following simple statements.

```
create table Test(id integer, data json);
insert into Test(id, data) values(1, '{"name": "vova"}');

select * from Test
where  json_extract(data, "$.name") IN ("vova", "mark");
```

Here select returns nothing. However, the query returns the expected row if i leave a single element in the array:

```
select * from Test
where  json_extract(data, "$.name") IN ("vova");
```

'json_extract' and 'where in' dont seem to like each other? Or i'm probably missing something?

Here is a link with an [example](https://paiza.io/projects/F8JJpN0gWmKEAPDdI0dFOA?language=mysql). Behaviour is the same when i run the queries locally.

Comment: study here,  you're missing something https://database.guide/json_extract-return-data-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you try to **evaluate**

```
json_extract(data, "$.name")
```

-> this will result to `"vova"`

meaning is with **double quotes**, treat your `IN` operator for this scenario as to select the string values, add single quotes.

```
select * from Test
where  json_extract(data, "$.name") IN ('"vova"', '"mark"');
```

Comment: oo, yeas, of course... Wonder why it correctly matches/not matches if there is a single element